# Gnome 3.4.2 image viewer crashes system

Tags: 12.04, gnome, crash

In my 12.04 system when I try to open a jpeg file on a thumb drive ( which may have been written by Windows) the system freezes completely and must be turned off to regain control. The failure mode: The image viewer displays its screen but the image area is black (empty). There does not seem to be a problem for screen captures or images on my hard drives. The thumb drive contains images that I created and saved so the images are not likely to contain any viruses. If no one has a solution please at least tell me how to disable the viewer while I get a replacement viewer.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had good experiences with "gthumb" in similar cases. Install it from the softwarecenter or typing "sudo ap-get install gthumb" in the terminal. Then right click on the image file, open with...